# Connection between eigenvalues and maximas on a elliptic paraboloid restricted on a circle

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I experimented with equations of the form: $\langle Ax,x \rangle$ with $A$ being a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and restricted the domain of $x$ to a circle of radius $k \ge 0$.

For my tests I used some standard equation like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%203x%5E2%2B(4x-3y)%5E2%2B2%5E2,%20%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%20%3C%3D%20k) and just manipulated the values slightly and checked wolfram alphas output (which results I naively took for granted.) I observed for these simple examples that all the max values lie on a line, which is actually not too surprising thinking about it.

(In the general case one might just get a point as the max value)

However I noticed that in these cases the slope of the line seems to be the max Eigenvalue of $A$, for which I have no clue, why this should be. Is there some truth behind this? Are the eigenvalues really connected to the maxima of a elliptic parabloid given the restriction on a circle? If yes, then why?

I would really happy, if there is "more" to my observation than just "picking" the parameters in a way so that it works. Especially if it can be formalised. Noneethless I will look further into it. I would be happy about any comments, answers bringing more light into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a real **symmetric** matrix, $\max \{\langle x, Ax \rangle: \|x\| = r \} = r^2 \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the greatest eigenvalue of $A$.  This follows from the [Min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).

EDIT:
It's not true for non-symmetric matrices.   But note that $$\langle x, Ax \rangle = \left\langle x, \frac{A + A^T}{2} x \right\rangle$$
so instead of the greatest eigenvalue of $A$ you should take the greatest 
eigenvalue of $(A + A^T)/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very insightful.